# OpenApi compilation returning paths as "jsonobject" randomly

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, openapi, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I'm developing a Java API which exposes multiple endpoints and it is deployed in a Google Cloud project.
We are using Endpoints Framework from Google to compile an openapi.json file. This file is used to deploy endpoints services.

For some reason, sometimes, this compilation gives some method paths as "jsonobject".

Example:

```
"/portalMail/v0.1/jsonobject": {
   "post": {
    "operationId": "PortalMailUpdateRead",
    "parameters": [
     {
      "in": "body",
      "name": "body",
      "required": false,
      "schema": {
       "$ref": "#/definitions/JsonMap"
      }
     }
    ],
    "responses": {
     "200": {
      "description": "A successful response",
      "schema": {
       "$ref": "#/definitions/JsonMap"
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
```

Definition:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "updateRead",httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.POST)
    public JSONObject updateRead( JSONObject json) 
            throws BadRequestException, IOException, InternalServerErrorException, ParseException, AuthenticationException {
        ...
```

I have tried adding a path to @ApiMethod definition, but this changes another different method to "jsonobject"

Comment: What happens if you add a path to all the methods? Does it still generates a random function as JSONObject?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet for all the methods. I guess that's the last to go. Anyway it should take it automatically as @Api is defined and others work. I would like to know if this is related to our definition (which follows documentation) or a framework error... Updating when I add all paths manually.

Comment: It's not suppose to be a framework error, If I am to guess, there is something in your definition that is randomly generating this bug, that is why I asked for the path on all methods, because it would "force" the definition to follow what you specified, try it and let me know.